# What is the eml network interface in Fedora linux?

Tags: linux, networking, fedora

When I run '`netstat -rn`' on my Fedora linux box, I get the following:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.4.202.250    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 em1
10.4.202.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 em1
```

What is the meaning of '`eml`' in the IFace column? I thought it had to be something like eth0.

Comment: That's a number one, not an "ell".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedded NICs are em1, em2 etc. they used to be eth0, eth1 before Fedora 15.

You might be able to change it according to [this article](http://rackerhacker.com/2011/09/25/getting-back-to-using-eth0-in-fedora-15/). (Disclaimer: I have not done what is suggested on the link.)